# How to import modules from a different directory in python

Tags: python, module

I have written a module and stored it in a location say x and then I am running a program from a different location y. Now, I want to import that module in x. 
How can I do that?

I have tried doing the following before importing but it didn't work for scripts -

```
os.chdir(x)
```

I want to utilise only the default modules available in Python 3.8.1.

Comment: Could you update your question to show the directory structure you are working with?

Comment: already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4383571/importing-files-from-different-folder)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Importing files from different folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4383571/importing-files-from-different-folder)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually it is answered in the following link:

[Importing files from different folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4383571/importing-files-from-different-folder)

I will try to summarise that:
 lets say your folder structure is like this

C:\Users\your_name\common_folder\
                                  x , y 
the folders x and y lie in the common_folder and let's assume you have python files x1.py inside x folder and y1.py inside y folder. 
So inside our y1 python file we might be writing something like this 
x1

```
import sys 
path = r'C:\Users\your_name\common_folder\x'
sys.path.insert(1, path)
import x1
```

then you can use any attribute inside the x python file and run

Cheers